# Are there in Alloy any cycles like for, while, etc?

Tags: alloy

**Can I write something like this:**

> for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
>
> while ()

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no cycles, loops, iterations, assignments, or any other imperative constructs in Alloy.

Comment: So is there any way to model a simple program with a loop? lets say int sum =0; for (int i =0;i< 5;i++) sum += i;   I need to check if Alloy can give me something for loop program or not. any official reference for your answer please. thanks